# Awaiting on a task from a different class

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I have a singleton class and a property that gets set from another class (class b), no problem. I want a different class (class a) to wait indefinitely until the property in the singleton class transitions true.  I want the most efficient way possible of doing this, so I felt tasks were ideal, but I can't effectively put all of the pieces together.  I don't want to continue to poll and sleep thread.sleep.

```
public class A
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if(!Monitor.Instance.HasChanged)
        {
            //await until the task in the Monitor class is complete
        }
    }
}

public class Monitor
{
    private static Monitor instance;
    private bool _hasChanged;
    private Monitor() { }

    public static Monitor Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Monitor();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }


    public bool HasChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return _hasChanged;
        }
        set
        {
            _hasChanged = value;
            if (_hasChanged)
            {
                //kick off a task
            }
        }
    }
}

public class B
{
    private static readonly Monitor _instance;
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Monitor.Instance.HasChanged = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `TaskCompletionSource` for this. You would do something like:

```
public class Monitor
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _changedTaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    public Task HasChangedTask => _changedTaskSource.Task;

    public bool HasChanged
    ...
    set
    {
        ...
        _changedTaskSource.TrySetResult(true);
    }
}
```

This sets up a task completion source and completes the task when the value changes. You would wait on it like so:

```
await Monitor.Instance.HasChangedTask;
```

One thing that is not clear from your question and you will need to address is resetting the task. To do so, just re-create the `TaskCompletionSource`.

Comment: Thanks, I will confirm this works tomorrow.  One last question since I am not really an expert.  

The consumer isn't currently an async method so the await has issues.  It would be easy to make the method async, but my question is, does this has any impact on any callers that previously used this as a non-async method?

Comment: @Roka Typically awaits will go all up the call chain. If you want synchronous waiting, `Task.Wait` is fine but be aware you could be blocking the thing that is trying to change your variable.